# Image sizes for different drawables

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a doubt about saving images in drawables for different device sizes. I want to ask that if I have an image of H:200,W:300 so for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi.xhdpi, xxhpdi and xxxhdpi, from which number we have to multiply in height and weight both for make it compatible for all size devices. Please reply me a simple answer, don't share any link.

Answer (score 0):

You should not consider making every drawable in same proportion for every devices but for UI . If you want to here are the ratios
Android takes hdpi as a base to calculate ratios.

```
MDPI:HDPI = 2/3
XHDPI:HDPI = 3/2
XXHDPI:HDPI = 2
XXXHDPI:HDPI = 8/3
```

Comment: Means for getting Height and Width for different size devices i have to follow these ratios?